# make insert statement in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

i'm learning VBA Excel and i have a problem with my project

Here the code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim score As String, result As String
score = Range("A1").Value

If score = "1" Then
   result = "book1"
ElseIf score = "2" Then
   result = "book2"
Else
   result = "wrong"
End If

Range("A1").Value = result
End Sub
```

i try to make the insert statement , when i insert "1" in "A1" then the result is "book1"

this is when the value is "1"

[image]

this is after i click enter button and the result is "book1"

[image]

and this is the result when i click enter button once more

[image]

it happen because when i click the first enter , the system read value is "1" so system return "book1", but when second enter the system read the value is "book1" and return "Wrong"

so how can i do to make the system only ready the first value every i enter or move cell

Thanks guys , sory for my bad english

Comment: Maybe add logic to don't do anything if the value is `book1` or `book2` already?

Comment: @BigBen it work when i only have 2 value , and no way i use that when i have so many value , maybe you have another suggestion ?

Comment: Use a lookup table or maybe a dictionary and then you can see if the cell's value should not be changed by comparing.

Comment: Use Choose, or two arrays if you talking many more values. Or simply exit sub when A1 is not numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add one more condition with OR operator for book1 & book2.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim score As String, result As String
score = Range("A1").Value

If score = "1" Or score="book1" Then
   result = "book1"
ElseIf score = "2" Or score="book2" Then
   result = "book2"
Else
   result = "wrong"
End If

Range("A1").Value = result
End Sub
```